# How do I make different decorations for each? (android material calendarview )

Tags: android

```
<MainActivity>

    dates = new ArrayList<>();
            dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 29));
            dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 30));
            materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new mDayDecorator(Color.RED, dates, MainActivity.this));
    
    dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 1));
            dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 2));
            dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 3));
            dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 4));
            dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 5));
            dates.add(CalendarDay.from(2021, 8, 6));
            materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new mDayDecorator(Color.YELLOW, dates, MainActivity.this));

<mDayDecorator>

    public class mDayDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {
    
        private Drawable drawable;
        private int color;
        private HashSet<CalendarDay> dates = new HashSet<>();
        private Context context;
    
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public mDayDecorator(int color, Collection<CalendarDay> dates, Context context) {
            this.color = color;
            this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
            drawable = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.more);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            return dates.contains(day);
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            drawable.setTint(color);
            view.setSelectionDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }
```

[image]

For example, I want to divide it into red for less than 3 days and yellow for less than 3 days, but I don't know how to control it.